# Proving resolution inference rule without truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I came across resolution inference rule stating:

> $((p\lor q)\land (\lnot p\lor r))\rightarrow(q\lor r)$

I googled a lot but what I get is either the proof using truth table or using this to prove others.

Then I tried something like this:

$LHS \equiv (p\lor q)\land (\lnot p\lor r)$

$\equiv (p\land \lnot p)\lor(p\land r)\lor (q\land \lnot p)\lor (q\land r)$

$\equiv (p\land r)\lor (q\land \lnot p)\lor (q\land r)$

But I cannot move further.

I also tried to prove the whole statement to true:

$(p\lor q)\land (\lnot p\lor r) \leftrightarrow (q\lor r)$

$\equiv \lnot((p\lor q)\land (\lnot p\lor r)) \lor (q\lor r)$

$\equiv \lnot(p\lor q)\lor \lnot(\lnot p\lor r) \lor (q\lor r)$

$\equiv (\lnot p\land \lnot q)\lor (p\land \lnot r) \lor (q\lor r)$

But I am unable to solve this further to equate this to TRUE. Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_simple_example) is not an equivalence.

The easiest way to derive it is to use the tautological equivalence between : $A \to B$ and $\lnot A \lor B$.

Thus :

> $(p∨q)∧(¬p∨r)$

is equivalent to :

> $(\lnot q \to p) \land (p \to r).$

Then, applying [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism), we get :

> $\lnot q \to r$

i.e. : $q \lor r$.

Comment: this was super easy

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, but isn't that an equivalence in itself?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal - the equivalence between $p \to q$ and $\lnot p \lor q$ **is** an equivalence indeed, but the rule of HS: "from $p \to q$ and $q \to r$, infer $p \to r$" is not.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, How come? What's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Using the equivalences $A\lor B\equiv \neg A \to B$ and $\neg \neg A \equiv A$, your formula

> $((p\lor q)\land (\lnot p\lor r))\rightarrow(q\lor r)$

is equivalent to:
$$
((\neg p\to q)\land (p \to r)) \to (\neg q\to r)\text{,}
$$
But $(\neg p\to q) \equiv (\neg q\to p)$, so the above formula is equivalent to:
$$
((\neg q\to p)\land (p \to r)) \to (\neg q\to r)\text{.}
$$
This should be straightforward to prove. Details on request.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of the resolution inference rule using a Fitch-style proof checker and
introduction and elimination rules:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/